# Добавление в словарь Python

Tags: python

Есть фрагмент кода который перебирает текст посимвольно и подсчитывает сколько раз встретилось слово и добавляет +1 в словарь

```
word = ""
dic = {}
for c in file:   
    if c not in punctuations:
        if word not in uninteresting_words:
            if c == " ":
                dic[word] += 1
                word = ""
                continue
            word += c
print(word)
```

Выходит ошибка: KeyError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну так вы до конца дочитайте ошибку

в приведённом вами коде не определены переменные `punctuations` и `uninteresting_words`

кроме того (скорее всего указанные выше переменные у вас все таки определены) **ошибка у вас вот тут**

```
dic[word] += 1
```

вы пишите в словарь при том, что изначально словарь пустой

по хорошему вам надо сделать так:

```
dic[word] = dic.get(word, 0) + 1
```

касательно логики работы программы, то тоже всё не слава Богу - **вот алгоритмические ошибки**:

1. алгоритм не распознает вот такие конструкции `"word1,word2"`

ваши символы пунктуации тоже должны служить разделителями слов

2. алгоритм неправильно обрабатывает вот такие конструкции `"word1 word2"`

последнее слово, если за ним не идет разделитель не будет подсчитано

3. вы работает с какими-то "неинтересными словами", но алгоритм использует это при проверке каждого символа, а не выделенного слова, поэтому если первое слово было неинтересным, то дальше алгоритм не выделит НИ ОДНОГО слова больше

По идее ваш код должен был бы выглядеть так:

```
file = "word1,word2 word3"

punctuations = [' ', ',']
uninteresting_words = [''] # чтобы не делать дополнительную проверку на пустое слово (возникает если несколько разделителей один за другим)

word = ""
dic = {}

for i in range(len(file)):
    if file[i] not in punctuations:
        word += file[i]

    if file[i] in punctuations or i == len(file) - 1:
        if word not in uninteresting_words:
            dic[word] = dic.get(word, 0) + 1
        word = ""

print(dic)
```